# Calling javascript validation function before submiting and calling servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am trying to validate the form and after that calling a servlet and it fails because form doesn't validete. I' ve pasted some code below. Could you give me some tips and help with this issue?

```js
function validateForm()
{
    if(document.frm.username.value=="")
    {
      alert("User Name can not be left blank");
      document.frm.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    else if(document.frm.pwd.value=="")
    {
      alert("Password can not be left blank");
      document.frm.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="/LoginExample/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="/LoginExample/js/validation.js"></script>
<title>Login example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" action="login" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<p> Enter user name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Enter password: <input name="password" type="password"><br> 
<input type="submit">
</p>
</form>

<a href="register.jsp"><input type="button" value="register" name="Sign in"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your javascript function as follows,

```
function validateForm(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the submit event.
    if(document.loginform.username.value=="")
    {
      alert("User Name can not be left blank");
      document.loginform.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    else if(document.loginform.password.value=="")
    {
      alert("Password can not be left blank");
      document.loginform.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
    else {
        document.loginform.submit();// fire submit event
    }
}
```

Also, pass the submit event in the function call like this,

```
<form name="loginform" action="login" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(event);">
```

the approach provided by Crowder is good, but you might also have to handle the submit event being fired anyway if the validation fails.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/yL4g562t/6/)

Comment: Still the same problem. After validating it redirects me to servlet.

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: This works! Blocking submit provides value by allowing you to validate the form driven by a servlet before submit. Once you submit, the servlet takes over to redirect the uri via RequestDispatcher and you cannot control validation then

Comment: @rnyunja, you are right, that's why preventDefault is useful and form is submitted only when client-side validations are cleared. But we shouldn't depend entirely on client-side validations only. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `document.frm` to refer to your form, but your form's name is `loginform`, not `frm`. So you want `document.loginform` if you want to rely on the automatically-created `document` properties.

I prefer not to rely on them. Instead, you might pass the form reference into your validation function:

```html
<form ... onSubmit="return validateForm(this);" ...>
```

...and then use the argument in your function:

```js
function validateForm(frm)
{
    if(frm.username.value=="")
    {
      alert("User Name can not be left blank");
      frm.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    else if(frm.pwd.value=="")
    {
      alert("Password can not be left blank");
      frm.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

(Of course, there I'm still relying on automatic properties, in this case on the form object. If I wanted to *really* avoid them, I could use `frm.querySelector("[name=username]")` for the username field and `frm.querySelector("[name=password]")` for the password field. All modern browsers, and IE8, have `querySelector`. But at least only relying on the ones on the form is a bit more contained than worrying about everything that gets dumped on `document`.)

Here's your form and the code above in a snippet, with the action modified to take you to google.com (and the method modified to GET; both of those mods are *just* for the demo): Try it with a blank username or password, and you'll note that the form does not submit:

```js
function validateForm(frm)
{
  if(frm.username.value=="")
  {
    alert("User Name can not be left blank");
    frm.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  else if(frm.pwd.value=="")
  {
    alert("Password can not be left blank");
    frm.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="loginform" action="http://google.com/search?q=kittens" method="get" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
<p> Enter user name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Enter password: <input name="password" type="password"><br> 
<input type="submit">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: About to gave same answer. But now don't want to duplicate the answer.His way of calling his form is wrong. Good catch

Comment: T.J. Crowder thank you very much for your help! It is almost that what I wanted but there is still one issue to deal with. When I left username blank I get a message so it's being validating but after that leaving empty username textbox servlet is being called. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @user3607625: It shouldn't be, not with the code you've shown. I've added a snippet to demonstrate.