# Is it possible to run a function after a form's required field validates?

Tags: angularjs, html, validation

I have a form that has several inputs that's required. Before pressing submit is there a way to run a function once the fields are validated?

Also not using jQuery but Angular =]

Comment: Do you want to run the function on submit if the form is valid, or just run the function when all the required field validates even if the form is not submitted?

Comment: @BlackMamba07 It's really only one field in the whole form that I need to run a function on once the field if filled out. I'll try your solution below however, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Calling javascript validation function before submiting and calling servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401516/calling-javascript-validation-function-before-submiting-and-calling-servlet)

this post should help you can also use ajax.

hope i was of some help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this its very useful.
[JQuery Validation Engine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
<form name='validForm' ng-submit='formSubmitted(validForm.$valid)'>
    <!--  Required Input Fields  -->
</form>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.formSubmitted = function (formValidFlag) {
    if(formValidFlag){
        //Your Actions
    }
}
```